# php syntax..giving error

Tags: php, string, syntax-error

```
$sql='UPDATE Reg_Stud SET Result=$perc WHERE RegID="$_SESSION['id']"';
```

Whts wrong with this syntax

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems like a legitimate question to me...

Comment: One that a basic tutorial and/or syntax highlighting makes trivial to answer yourself. Plus, it's poorly asked. (But that's not my downvote)

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

- Variable interpolation does not
  happen in single quotes.
- An un-escaped quote in a string
  prematurely terminates the string.

You can do:

```
$sql='UPDATE Reg_Stud SET Result='.$perc.' WHERE RegID='.$_SESSION['id'];
```

Comment: You can do this, if you want Bobby Tables to screw your database.

Comment: @delnan: How do you know the variables are not sanitized?

Comment: @delnen: I do not get? If you consider `$perc` (maybe it was `ctype_digit` checked?) and `$_SESSION['id']` (you set it yourself to an int) to be valid, then there is no chance Bobby Tables might attack. But obviously escaping them won't hurt you either ;)

Comment: I don't *know* the variables aren't sanitized, but come on, the odds are pretty good ;)

Comment: I had no idea who bobby tables was, im glad i know him now!